# c# combobox filtering one combobox based on the value of another combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, filter

I have 2 tables, product_items and category.
And 2 combobox. I want filter another combobox, after selected category.
Sorry for my bad english speak :), i tryed this 9h, and no solution get :/
My code how much i have writed.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select itemid, itemname, pcatid from produkti_items_tab", TestConnection);
            da.Fill(ds, "FillDropDown");

            comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["FillDropDown"].DefaultView;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "itemname";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "itemid";

            //============================================
            DataSet ddd = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter dada = new SqlDataAdapter("select pcatid, pcatname from produkti_cat_tab", TestConnection);
            dada.Fill(ddd, "FillDropDownzzz");

            comboBox2.DataSource = ddd.Tables["FillDropDownzzz"].DefaultView;
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "pcatname";
            comboBox2.ValueMember = "pcatid";
```

But i dont know what i should write here:

```
    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //how filter :/
}
```

Comment: on which condition you want to filter another combo box?

Comment: Can you give us a better explanation of what you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, need to test this, but, the DataView binded to the first combobox has a RowFilter property.
Setting this property to the appropriate condition should remove the items that doesn't belong to the current category selected

```
if(comboBox2.SelectedValue != null)
{
    DataView dv = comboBox1.DataSource as DataView;
    dv.RowFilter = "pcatid = " + comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Almost work :). When i press change, it really filter. But problem is on form load. I get error (cannot find column[system.data.DataRowView])

Comment: After this error, when form load i mannualy change combobox, it really filter. But on form load, now i getting error. ComboBox at form load show first category, and filter at start dont filter only after mannyaly change.

Comment: Code in form load, i already showwed UP. Nothing new. SomeHow i need put this filter in form load too, because in start combobox2 has value, but your code work after i change value. It mean somewhere i need put filter again.

Comment: So, are you telling me that in form_load you set the SelectedValue of the combobox2 to some predefined category? You could add  the same commands there using the predefined value for your category (something like `dv.RowFilter = "pcatid=" + yourDefaultCatValue.ToString();`

Comment: I found where is error.
somehow i need stop this event, when form load.'code' private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

Comment: Maybe in your if() statement, i need somethink && and put like button pressed.

Comment: I will wait for somethink for control click :)

Comment: Solved with this event :) private void comboBox2_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Or remove the event handler in the designer, do your initialization in form load and before exit readd your handler using code: combobox2.SelectedIndexChanged += new combobox2_SelectedIndexChanged;